# Alternative to xinput for Wayland?

Tags: 17.10, wayland, xinput

Is there an alternative to xinput on Wayland?
I realised one of my gnome-shell-extension does not work properly due to the fact that xinput gives limited information about the devices under wayland (of course because it is written to work on xorg).

`xinput --list` on xorg:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech Performance MX                   id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech MX Master                        id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ HID 046a:0023                             id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ DLL07D1:01 044E:120B                      id=16   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ DualPoint Stick                           id=17   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated_Webcam_HD: Integrate           id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HID 041e:30d3                             id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HID 046a:0023                             id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID events                          id=18   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID 5 button array                  id=19   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=20   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=21   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech MX Master                        id=22   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HID 046a:0023                             id=23   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

`xinput --list` on wayland:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer:15                       id=6    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-relative-pointer:15              id=7    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ xwayland-keyboard:15                      id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Now my question: **Is there an alternative with similar features on wayland?**

Current system is Ubuntu 17.10 on Dell Latitude 5580

Comment: Have a look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/426944/what-is-the-wayland-equivalent-of-xinput-list which lists `libinput list-devices`.

Comment: thx a lot. Looks promising

Comment: No so promising, this only addresses `xinput list` not `xinput` in general.